# tar does not create backup

Tags: backup, lvm, tar

I want to use LVM snapshots for backing up my system.

I have two LVM volumes called "root_lv" and "home_lv" in the volume group called "myvol". I've created root directory snapshot

```
sudo lvcreate -s -l 70G -n rootsnap /dev/myvol/root_lv
```

After that I mounted it to `/mnt`:

```
sudo mount /dev/myvol/rootsnap /mnt
```

I expected that that command would create backup of my snapshot except `/home`, `/media` and etc.

```
sudo tar -cvpzf rootbackup.tar.gz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/run --exclude=/dev --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/3GB.swap --exclude=rootbackup.tar.gz /mnt
```

But `tar` said that it could not create an empty archive. The only way I can create backup that way is chroot'ed to /mnt and run command from there.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are asking it to archive /mnt, and then telling it to exclude /mnt with the option `--exclude=/mnt` which excludes everything, hence there is nothing in the archive and you get the error message.

If i understand what you are doing correctly, you should drop the `--exclude=/mnt` option.